# Python speech_recognition doesn't understand me and returns UnknwonValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

If I run speech_recognition module in terminal it still doesn't understands me and returns (Oops! couldn't get that).

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=2)
    audio = r.listen(source)                   
try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:             #Microphone recognizer 
    print("Listening....")
    r.pause_threshold = 1                   #use for recognizer hold
    r.energy_threshold=1000
    audio = r.listen(source)                #use for listen

try:                                        #try use for by chance any error bypass
    print("Recognizing.......")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in") #This is use for language 
    print(f"User Said : {query}\n")
    speak("okay")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Say that again Please......")
    speak("Say that again Please")
    return "None"
return query
```

Comment: Please don't just post a code snippet as your answer. It helps users understand your solution & more lightly to attract upvotes.